# How can I determine if a postgresql db has a JDBC driver?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, elasticsearch

I would like to dump static data from a postgresql into elastic search. A JDBC driver is required for the db but I cannot figure out if the db already has it or not.

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to find out?

http://studiofrenetic.com/blog/a-river-flowing-from-postgresql-to-elasticsearch/

Comment: The "DB" does not need a JDBC driver. The _client_ (where you run your Java program) needs the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Jorg's JDBC River supports postgresql -

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc#postgresql